# Finding Current Month And paste sum to it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste the sum of total days value to current month.

this is what I have so far, but it wont paste the total to the containers column depending on the current month

[image]

This is my code

```
Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '
    For i = 2 To 13
        If Cells(i, 5) = Month Then Cells(i, 6) = Cells(34, 2)
        Cells(i, 6).Select
        Selection.copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason that the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) won't work?

Comment: Im a beginner in VBA, not sure how it works

Comment: Why not a Pivot Table Sam?

Comment: I havent used Pivot Table.. is there a good pivot table tutorial that would explain how to make one.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576

Comment: You do not need VBA or Formulas to achieve what you want. In few clicks you can get what you want and that too in a presentable format ;)

Comment: But then how can I make it pastes the total sum to the current month.. this report is updated daily.

Comment: Okay Ill read more into Pivot tables.. Thank you

Comment: Still dont get how to make Pivot Tables and how to select which month to add the total too, if possible, can you please help

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Scripting Dictionary like this:

```
Sub SumContainersByMonth()
    Dim c As Range, DataRange As Range
    Dim count As Double
    Dim key As String
    Dim k, Keys, Items
    Dim dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set DataRange = Range("A2", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    For Each c In DataRange
       key = DateSerial(Year(c), Month(c), 1)
       count = c.Offset(0, 1) + dict(key)
       dict(key) = count
    Next

    Keys = dict.Keys
    Items = dict.Items

    Range("E2").Resize(UBound(Keys) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Keys)
    Range("F2").Resize(UBound(Items) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Items)

End Sub
```

---

I would make a few changes to your project setup and subtotal the data.

Here is how

I would insert a Month-Year column to the left of Day.  The value of Month-Year should equal that of the Day column but it's format would be MMM-YY.

[image]

In the Data tab click Subtotals.

[image]

Apply the settings in the image below.

[image]

To the left of the row numbers click <kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>, or <kbd>3</kbd> to choose how to display your data.

[image]

Comment: ThANK YOU, I WILL TRY IT